# Blur in recyclerview

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

i want to make some blur in the edges of the recycler view, as you can see in the picture, the top and bottom part are "cut", i would like to give the sensation of disappearing (like the second image (that image is on figma, so i havent made it on android)), its possible to do that? I dont like the cutted version at all

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use in RecyclerView

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recycler"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:fadingEdge="horizontal|vertical"
                android:fadingEdgeLength="24dp"
                android:requiresFadingEdge="horizontal|vertical"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_below="@+id/ll_serch" />
```

output here:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried something like this in your xml (RecyclerView):

```
android:fadingEdge="vertical|horizontal"
android:fadingEdgeLength="50dp"
android:requiresFadingEdge="vertical|horizontal"
```

And, you need to remove your bottom margin, otherwise your fading edges wouldn't look as you wish.